# Telerik Rad Scheduler Windows Form Right To Left Text

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radscheduler

I use RadScheduler For My C# Windows Application
and my Culture is Fa (Persian Iran)
but I have a problem with the Show Appointment Text
I changed RightToLeft to True but it did not work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mostafa,
It seems that you hit a known issue related to the RightToLeft support for RadScheduler. You can track its progress, subscribe for status changes and add your comments on the following link:
https://feedback.telerik.com/winforms/1371186-fix-radscheduler-persian-text-is-rendered-in-reversed-order-in-appointmentelement-with-rtl-radscheduler

Feel free to use the suggested solution and see whether it would improve the text rendering on your end.

Comment: thanks, how can I contact you?

Comment: Hi, Mostafa, the following article is quite useful on this topic: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/knowledge-base/submit-support-tickets